# UITabBarController embedded in a NavigationController

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I know this question has been asked before and the solutions I've heard is to not use a UITabBarController but to add a UITabbar to a view and push its corresponding viewController to the navigation controller. 
However, when I use this method, I can see the tab bar, but I can't display the tabbaritems on the tabbar. It only shows a tabbar on the bottom. I tried to setup a tabbardelegate that handles the button response but obviously with no buttons that seemed pointless.

Any good advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They tell you not to do it because it doesn't work.

You can have a tabBar that looks like this:
[Nav][Nav][Nav]

But you can't have:

Nav

[tabs]